# SQLPackage with Script Action does not produce any Copy Always scripts

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

Using sqlpackage with Action=Script, I get a deployment script. But I don't get any copies of the scripts with property Copy To Output Directory = Copy always.

However, when publishing from within Visual Studio, I do get these files.

Why is that? By design?

I want to trigger a build using sqlpackage (or something else), including these scripts..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using something like this:

```
msbuild .\DBName\DBName.sqlproj /t:build /p:Configuration="Local"

sqlpackage /a:script /tsn:TargetServer /sf:.\DBName\sql\Local\DBName.dacpac /pr:.\DBName\Publish\TargetServer.publish.xml /op:.\Scripts\DBName-TargetServer.sql
```

(where TargetServer and DBName make sense for your projects and the dacpac was just built)
/a:Script - action == generate script 
/sf - dacpac for source
/pr - Publish Profile to use
/op - output filename

I usually combine that with the following to get a deploy report for changes:

```
sqlpackage /a:DeployReport /tsn:ServerName /sf:.\DBName\sql\Local\DBName.dacpac /pr:.\DBName\Publish\ServerName.publish.xml /op:.\Scripts\DBName-ServerName.xml
```

Comment: Thank's Peter, I will look into msbuild, but I also need to include my script files somehow.

Comment: Got it. I posted a bunch on SSDT on my blog. You can find those posts here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html

The one you are probably looking for around different scripts per environment is: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

Comment: @PeterSchott does this mean that there is not option to include the creation of a deploymentreport when using another action like "publish"? Does the report have to be created in a separates step / execution? Isn't this a waste of resources?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it through SQLPackage, but there must be some way to do it programmatically. It might be an option w/ MSBuild.exe, but every time I tried to use that it seemed to want to publish my project and that was definitely not the behaviour I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

SqlPackage.exe works against Dacpac files such as the one built by your project. That's intended to be a single artifact containing all of the information needed to deploy your schema to a database. It doesn't have any knowledge of anything that's not in the dacpac so that's why using a:/script doesn't produce those files.

If you want to include some scripts as part of the deployment why not mark them as pre or post-deployment scripts? That will incude them in the dacpac and automatically execute them during publish. If you have multiple scripts you can write one main script and use the "[:r filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx)" SQLCMD command to pull in the other script contents. At build time a single merged postdeployment.sql script is created and saved in the dacpac - you can actually see the contents by renaming the file to a .zip which can help you understand what SqlPackage and other tools will work with.

As mentioned by @Peter-Schott in the other answer, you can call msbuild from the command line to actually build the project and even to publish the project directly if you use the /t:publish command.

Comment: Thank's Kevin. Pre/post scripts is one option. I need multiple post and pre deployment scripts, and they must be different depending on the target (DEV/TEST/PROD). I plan to put all grants and such in these files..

Comment: Well, the sections can work depending on your variables. I did that w/ setting different permissions per environments. I think some others have come up w/ some interesting ways to include/not include scripts, but I haven't played with that too much. Ed Elliott might have some ideas on his blog.